# How to parse options without any argument using optparse module

Tags: python

How can I pass options without any argument and without passing any default argument?

For example:

```
./log.py --ipv4
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While lajarre's answer is correct, it's important to note outparse is considered deprecated.

I suggest using the newer [argparse module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) instead.

So your code would look like:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is my description')
parser.add_argument('--ipv4', action='store_true', dest='ipv4')
```

Using -foo or --foo flags makes the arguement optional. [See this documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#required) for more about optional arguments.

***Edit:*** And here's the specific documentation for the [add_argument method](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument).

***Edit 2:*** Additionally, if you wanted to accept either -foo or --foo you could do

```
parser.add_argument('-ipv4', '--ipv4', action='store_true', dest='ipv4')
```

Answer (score 15):

```
parser.add_option("--ipv4", action="store_true", dest="ipv4")
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#handling-boolean-flag-options

Comment: Why does this only have one up vote (mine!... and yours too @Murkantilism ) ?